# How to copy string and add more words to the new string?

Tags: c, string

If I have this code:

```
int main ()
{
    char *string = "beach" ;
    char newString[50];
    strcpy(newString,string);
    return(0);
}
```

After running it, `newString` will be "beach", right? If I want `newString` to be "beach.jpg", how should I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stick with your code

```
int main ()
{
    char *string = "beach" ;
    char newString[50];
    strcpy(newString,string);
    strcat(newString,".jpg");
    return(0);
}
```

I assume here enough space in `newString`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any inbuilt functions to be used..

```
int i=0;
for(;newString[i]!='\0';i++);
newString[i++]='.';
newString[i++]='j';
newString[i++]='p';
newString[i++]='g';
newString[i]='\0';
```

If you prefer to use inbuilt functions then, you can include this line.

```
strcat(newString,".jpg");
```

Comment: This answer will not use any inbuilt function whereas the other one does

Comment: Edited.. and deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply initialize the array with the string literal and later use the standard library function `strcat` to append `".jpg"` to it. Make sure that the array `string` is large enough else `strcat` may overrun the buffer invoking undefined behaviour. Also, note that `return` is not a function.

```
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LEN 50

int main(void) {
    char string[MAX_LEN] = "beach";
    strcat(string, ".jpg");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

```
strcat(strcpy(newstring, string), ".jpg");
```

Always remember to ensure enough space in newstring.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main ()
{
    char *string = "beach" ;
    char newString[50];
    sprintf(newString,"%s.jpg",string);
    printf("%s",newString);
    return(0);
}
```

with sprintf you can concat the multiple strings.